# Add attribute to HTML tag depending on inner pattern using PHP

Tags: php, regex, xpath, domdocument

I actually already found a workable solution and its called regex. Yes i know, it has been said zillions of times not to use regex for HTML parsing. But here is the thing, as the title says, it depends on the inner HTML text, which need to follow a certain pattern. So i need to use regex anyway! I tried using the DOM library first but i failed.

So my actual question is if there is a best practice for this issue? Anyway, here is what I've got:

HTML before:

```
<section> 
    {foo:bar}
</section>
```

PHP:

```
// I'm not a regex ninja, but this seems to do the job

$regexTag = "/<(?!body|head|html|link|script|\!|\/)(\w*)[^>]*>[^{]*{\s*[^>]*:\s*[^>]*\s*[^}]}/";
// $match[0] "<section> {foo:bar}"
// $match[1] "section"


preg_match_all($regexTag,$html, $match); 


for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($match[0]); $i++) { 
    $pos = (strlen($match[1][$i])+1);
    $str = substr_replace($match[0][$i], " class='foo'", $pos, 0);
    $html = str_replace($match[0][$i], $str, $html);
}
```

HTML after:

```
<section class='foo'> 
    {foo:bar}
</section>
```

Comment: Which tags are you trying to add an attribute to exactly?

Comment: Any tag in the body section, just the inner html need to match.

Comment: By depending on inner pattern, can you thoroughly explain what you mean?

Comment: Well, i use this as my template base. The inner html (curly brackets) will be replaced as well later on . I need to check somehow that this parent tag includes template content, to distinguish it from other tags.

Comment: If I were you I would use preg_replace_callback to avoid that mess of strlen, strpos and str_replace that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex is not the correct tool for this job. Stick with the DOM parser approach. Here's a quick solution using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) class.

Use [`getElementsByTagName('*')`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get *all* the tags, and then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) to check if the tag name is in the list of disallowed tags.

Then use a regex with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) to check if the text content follows the `{foo:bar}` pattern. If it does, add the new attributes one by one, [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) method:

```
// An array containing all attributes
$attrs = [
    'class' => 'foo'
    /* more attributes & values */
];

$ignored_tags = ['body', 'head', 'html', 'link', 'script'];

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $tag) 
{
    // If not a disallowed tag
    if (!in_array($tag->tagName, $ignored_tags)) 
    {
        $textContent = trim($tag->textContent);

        // If $textContent matches the format '{foo:bar}'
        if (preg_match('#{\s*[^>]*:\s*[^>]*\s*[^}]}#', $textContent)) 
        {
            foreach ($attrs as $attr => $val)
                $tag->setAttribute($attr, $val);
        }
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<section class="foo"> 
    {foo:bar}
</section>
```

Comment: But because i don't know the name of the tags yet, i would do sth like this: $elements = $dom->documentElement->childNodes;  and then loop thru this list? $dom->getElementsByTagName($elements[$i])

Comment: @domizai: Oh, I see. You didn't mention that in your question. Do you want to loop through all the tags other than `body|head|html|link|script`?

Comment: That's correct! I thought 'any' tags means all tags. My bad.

Comment: @domizai: Sorry, you'd mentioned it in a comment — I didn't see it until now. I've updated the answer with an alternative approach. See if that suits your needs.

Comment: Oh you changed the code, didn't see it. Yea your method is way simpler!

Answer (score 0):

So this works

```
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;

for ($i = $elements->length-1; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
   $element = $elements->item($i); 
   $tag =  $element->nodeName;

   foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag) as $tag) {
       ...
```

I dunno though, i still feel more comfortable with regex, haha. But i guess this is the way to go.